# CakePHP: How to Format non-decimal Currencies with Symbol AFTER the value?

Tags: cakephp, currency

I'm trying to format French Canadian currencies in my multi-lingual application. I'm using an extended version of the NumberHelper where I've used `addFormat` to add a format for French Canadian, but the problem is that I can't find a way to tell CakePHP to move the dollar sign to appear *after* the amount.

For example, $3.57 should display as 3,57$ for French Canadian.

If I set the `after` property to be "$" then when a value is only cents, it looks like dollars, so $0.57 becomes 57$ which looks like 57 dollars.

I tried setting the locale using the PHP `setlocale` and `money_format` commands, but it screws up my MySQL calls because I have to convert all the currency values back to English for all my CRUD operations, which I don't have time for at the moment.

Any ideas on how I could get this to work in a maintainable way in CakePHP?

Thanks in advance to all the experienced, big brains out there.

-Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I extended the NumberHelper class and simply added my needed currencies in the `__construct()` method. Then I built another method called `money` that just brute-forced the conversion of any amount if my language setting was French Canadian to both make sure that the spaces thousands was non-breaking, and to add a spaced dollar sign AFTER the amount (complete code below).

I'm not really happy with this, but it gets the job done. If anybody can suggest how to use set a user's locale in PHP without mangling the database inserts, I'd be interested.

```
class CurrencyHelper extends NumberHelper {

var $helpers = array('Session');

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->addFormat('en_ca', array(
        'before' => '$',
        'after' => false,
        'zero' => 0,
        'places' => 2,
        'thousands' => ',',
        'decimals' => '.',
        'negative' => '()',));

    $this->addFormat('fr_ca', array(
        'before' => false,
        'after' => false,
        'zero' => 0,
        'places' => 2,
        'thousands' => ' ',
        'decimals' => ',',
        'negative' => '()',));
}

function money($amount = 0, $useLocale = true) {
    $locale = 'en_ca';
    if ($useLocale) {
        $s = new CakeSession();
        $locale = $s->read('Config.language');
        unset($s);
    }

    $result = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $this->currency($amount, $locale)) . ($locale == 'fr_ca' ? ' $' : '');
    return $result;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a _setLanguage() method in my AppController that I call in the beforeFilter() callback to setup the language. I added this code to configure a french canadian currency

```
if($this->Session->read('Config.language') == 'fra') {
    CakeNumber::addFormat('fr_CA', array(
        'wholeSymbol' => '$',
        'wholePosition' => 'after',
        'thousands' => ' ',
        'decimals' => ',',
        'negative' => '()',));
    CakeNumber::defaultCurrency('fr_CA');
}
```

This should work in CakePHP 2.3 or higher.